# java pdfbox printerjob wrong size on label

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I create with my application a PDF file which has exactly the dimensions of the label. When I print this file with Adobe Reader, the result is from the top. When I print it in Java, not everything is printed.

1. = Adobe, 2. pdfbox

[image: 1. = Adobe, 2. pdfbox]

```
public static PrintService choosePrinter(String printerName) {
    PrintService[] service = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices(); // list of printers
    PrintService printService = null;
    int count = service.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (service[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(printerName)) {
            printService = service[i];
            i = count;
        }
    }
    return printService;
}

public static void printPDF(String fileName, PrinterSetting printerSetting) throws IOException, PrinterException {
    PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(new File(fileName));
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

    // define custom paper
    Paper paper = new Paper();
    paper.setSize( printerSetting.getPageHeight(), printerSetting.getPageWidth()); // 1/72 inch
    paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, paper.getWidth(), paper.getHeight());

    // custom page format
    PageFormat pageFormat = new PageFormat();
    pageFormat.setPaper(paper);
    pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);

    // override the page format
    Book book = new Book();
    // append all pages
    PDFPrintable pdfPrintable = new PDFPrintable(pdf, Scaling.SHRINK_TO_FIT);
    book.append(pdfPrintable, pageFormat, pdf.getNumberOfPages());
    job.setPageable(book);

    PrintService printService = choosePrinter(printerSetting.getPrinterName());
    if(printService != null)
        job.setPrintService(printService);

    job.print();
}
```

Comment: It also prints correctly in Java when calling the dialog once.

Comment: Please try the trick mentioned at the bottom of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3117

Comment: But the cut off is on top. 
If I set the printer to default paper via the settings window then it works. If I make this change via code then it will not work :/

Comment: default paper would be `Paper paper = PrinterJob.defaultPage().getPaper();`

Comment: I wish I could help more but I don't have your printer. You'd need to work this out yourself... try printing with ordinary java graphics. Are you able to print a (visible) rectangle that you draw on the print graphics device? If no, then java is at fault. If yes, then whatever you did should be used for PDFBox.

Comment: Another idea: what happens if you add a rotation to the PDF, (page.setRotate(90)) and switch coordinates of the media box and then print the PDF as portrait.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Heute habe ich den Trick mit dem 
Paper paper = PrinterJob.defaultPage().getPaper();
ausprobiert. Dabei wird leider einer java.awt.print.PrinterException: Paper's imageable width is too small. geworfen. 

Papier (H x W): 252.0 x 78.9
Imageable (H x W): 108.0 x -65
ImageableX: 72
ImageableY: 72

Die -65 stören ihn anscheinend. Wenn ich diese auf 65 setze, ist die Seite leer.